# How to run npm variables during run time (process.env.SERVER) on a windows machine using Cmder?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, webdriver-io

I have created a NodeJs, Selenium and webdriverio framework, but struggling to run npm variables during rune time (The same setup works on a mac).

My wdio file:

```
if(process.env.SERVER == "prod") {
    baseUrl = 'http://www.google.com';
}

exports.config = {
```

Running the following command in Cmder:

```
SERVER=prod npm test
```

However I get the following message:

```
'SERVER' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Operating system: Window 10 pro
Bash console: Cmder.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest behavior seems to be `SET SERVER=prod && npm test`. `SET /?` claims that it:

> `Displays, sets, or removes cmd.exe environment variable`

I guess that should be accessible through Node.

However, contrary to usual shells, setting a variable seems to be a command in itself, hence requiring an explicit separator before the next command: here `&&` to one-line it, you could also just hit Enter before calling `npm` - and `;` doesn't seem to work.